# Angularjs - get selected item text of select without ng-option

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

I have a dropdownlist -

```
 <select ng-model="contact.type" id="select_{{$index}}" ng-change="changedValue()" class="searchCriteria">
                    <option>Policy Number</option>
                    <option>Insured Name</option>
                </select>
```

I want to get the selected item using angularjs. So far I have tried

```
$scope.changedValue = function () {
    alert($(".searchCriteria option:selected").html());
}
```

among other things. But each time the alert shows "undefined". How do I get the selected option text?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the $scope variable,

```
$scope.changedValue = function () {
    alert($scope.contact.type);
}
```

Comment: it returns `Value` , How Get text of selected index ?